# Permissions in GIT

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I have a computer after my previous colleague who has already quit work, not knowing why git is blocking my access to upload repositories on github, does anyone have any idea why?

```
C:\Users\...\Desktop\test>git push -u origin master
remote: Permission to .../nest.git denied to (previousUser).
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/.../nest.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

Comment: You need to update your `.gitconfig` file, which propably still refers to the previous owner.

Comment: where can i find this file?

Comment: Are you using `SSH` or `HTTPS`? If you're not sure you can check with `git remote -v`.

Comment: @NickMcCurdy i'm using https

Comment: The credential helper probably has their old login cached, which has probably been disabled. You may need to log in with your own account.

Comment: @NickMcCurdy can you show me list of command which can i use to change m credentials?

Comment: @NickMcCurdy can you help?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15381198/remove-credentials-from-git